# Get datewise result as grouped from MySql Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to select data from a Mysql table as grouped data. I have a table like below in MySql Database.

```
+-----------------------+
|   date         name   |
+-----------------------+
| 12/02/2015   computer |
| 12/02/2015   mouse    |
| 12/02/2015   Book     |
| 13/02/2015   Paper    |
| 13/02/2015   Pen      |
| 13/02/2015   Pencil   |
+-----------------------+
```

I would like to display data like below.

```
+---------------+
| date          |
+---------------+
| 12/02/2015    |
+---------------+
| name          |
+---------------+
| computer      |
| mouse         |
| Book          |
+---------------+
| date          |
+---------------+
| 13/02/2015    |
+---------------+
| name          |
+---------------+
| Paper         |
| Pen           |
| Pencil        |
+---------------+
```

I need the Query. Thanks

**Update**

I would not like to use `group_concat()`.I think there are other ways to do that. There are some limitation of `group_concat()` like it can concate certain amount of text and I am facing that type of problem.

I think here are some solutions  [MySQL Query with Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199945/mysql-query-with-group-by?rq=1)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What did you manage?

Comment: A similar question came up recently. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30699602/how-to-formulate-query-to-show-all-courses-taken-by-a-person

Comment: Write your query we will edit it.

Comment: You should handle the display in the application (php) code.  Your format is not really a "database" format.  For instance, you are missing different types in one column.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) conditional SQL function to perform this task. It will group the results of your query by date, so you will have an order of names sorted by date :

```
SELECT T.date, T.name
FROM   TABLE T
GROUPE BY T.date, T.name -- T.name is not necessary
```

Which will be display as below :

```
DATE       NAME
-------------------
12/02/2015 Computer
12/02/2015 Mouse
12/02/2015 Book
13/02/2015 Paper
13/02/2015 Pen
13/02/2015 Pencil
```

Comment: this query will not return all the values, the mouse,book,pen and pencil will not be returned. you have to concat the names into one value

Answer (score 0):

```
select date, group_concat(name) as names
from table
group by date
```

the result will be

12/02/2015   compute,mouse,book

13/02/2015   paper,pen,pencil

then you can loop the result and explode the names value into array

Comment: I looking for a solution without `group_concat()`. Thanks